# Lodash to check object property on array elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I want to use lodash to find a property of an object at a specific array element.

Lets say I am hitting an api and getting response which sets it to the react state "personsDetails" (whose initial value was null), so now it becomes

```
let personsDetails=[{name:'king',id:2},{name:'queen',id:3}] //sometimes i get 1 object and sometimes 2
```

now when i want to access "name" property of 2nd object i do

```
personsDetails && personsDetails[1] && personsDetails[1].name
```

So is there any shorted syntax of accessing it via using lodash ? If the values doesnt exist i need null

As far as i know _get property works with object only so here i am dealing with array and then object

Comment: no need to use any library, you can use `personsDetails?.[1]?.name` instead of `personsDetails && personsDetails[1] && personsDetails[1].name`. this is `optional chaning (?.)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: @MohitSharma the project which i have is running a very old version of node, so optional chaining is not supported, and we dont want to change the webpack currently due to some reasons, so with already installed lodash, i want to get it work if its possible  or maybe any other way which works on node 13 :)

Comment: "*As far as i know _get property works with object only so here i am dealing with array and then object*" 1. Arrays are objects. 2. Lodash does also explicitly support syntax for accessing arrays anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `get` and set the default as `null`

```js
let personsDetails=[{name:'king',id:2},{name:'queen',id:3}] 
let res = _.get(personsDetails, '1.name',null) //or _.get(personsDetails, '[1].name',null)
console.log(res)

console.log(_.get(undefined, '1.name',null))
console.log(_.get([], '1.name',null))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

or can use `nth` along with `get` and set the default as `null`

```js
let personsDetails=[{name:'king',id:2},{name:'queen',id:3}] 

let res = _.get(_.nth(personsDetails,1),'name',null)
console.log(res)

console.log(_.get(_.nth([],1),'name',null))
console.log(_.get(_.nth(undefined,1),'name',null))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```